# CopyPicture method of range class failed - using vbs script

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `vbs` scropt that I schedule using taskmanager in windows7. 
the `vbs` script opens an excel workbook and runs a certain macro.

This all works pretty well for most cases except this example where I want to copy a picture in the workbook to an email. the `vba` works fine when i open the workbook and run the `vba` but when i run the `vbs`(double click on it) I get an error.

This is the line that throws the issue `Plage.CopyPicture` with `CopyPicture method of Range class failed`

I have done a bit of searching on this and came [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911957/excel-vba-optimization) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740062/copypicture-method-of-range-class-failed-sometimes). From this the best solution I could fine is by doing this in my `vbs` script `myExcelWorker.Visible = True`

Whilst this works, which is good, I would like to know if there is a another way without making it visible? Does anyone on here have any ideas?

**NOTE:** I don't fully understand why it works when it is made visible. Is there anything I can do with the clipboard.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------EDIT1-------------------------------------------------**
I tried adding `Plage.CopyPicture 2` as per comment below and got the same error 
`Run-time error ‘-2147417848 (80010108)’ Method ‘CopyPicture’ of Object ‘Range’ failed` I then press debug and VB editor comes up with the error, I press f8 again and i get this error `Run-time error ‘1004’: CopyPicture method of Range class failed`

**Below are my scripts just for reference:**

VBS script:

```
'need to update WBName & MacroName here as this is fairly generic

dim WshShell
set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

dim strPath
strPath = WshShell.CurrentDirectory 

Dim myExcelWorker
Set myExcelWorker = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'myExcelWorker.Visible = True ' this makes excel visible 

dim oWorkBook
dim WBName

WBName = "\WBwithMacro.xlsm" 'WB to be opened  

dim MacroName 
MacroName = "'" & strpath & WBName & "'!UpdateChart_EDW_LTE" 'Macro Name to be run 

'Write Start+strPath to log file
Call WriteLog("Start_XXX",strPath,"var3")

'Write Mid+strPath+WBName to log file
Call WriteLog("Mid___XXX",strpath & WBName,"var3")

'open WB for running macro
'set oWorkBook = myExcelWorker.Workbooks.open(strpath & WBName) 'for WB WITHOUT password 
Set oWorkBook = myExcelWorker.Workbooks.Open(strpath & WBName,,,,"","Password") 'for WB with password

'Write MacroName to log file
Call WriteLog("Mid___XXX",MacroName,"var3")

myExcelWorker.Run MacroName

myExcelWorker.DisplayAlerts = False 'this is required so the WB will save without being prompted 

oWorkBook.Save
oWorkBook.Close

myExcelWorker.DisplayAlerts = True ' set it back to true again as it is good practice

myExcelWorker.Quit

'Write End to log file
Call WriteLog("End___XXX","t2","t3")

set oWorkBook = Nothing
set myExcelWorker = Nothing
set WshShell = Nothing

'sub to write to log file
Sub WriteLog(var1, var2, var3)

Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Wscript.Echo "VBSStart.vbs is running" 
Dim ObjFso
Dim StrFileName
Dim ObjFile
Dim FlName 

'WScript.Echo var1 & ",,,," & var2 

FlName = "TestFile.txt"
StrFileName = objShell.CurrentDirectory & "\" & FlName
Set ObjFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Creating a file for writing data
set ObjFile = ObjFso.OpenTextFile(StrFileName, 8, True) 

 'Writing a string into the file
ObjFile.WriteLine(var1 & "," & var2 & "," & var3 & "," & now)

'Closing the file
ObjFile.Close

' Using Set is mandatory
Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

VBA part(in excel workbook):

```
Function createPng(Namesheet, nameRange, nameFile)
    Debug.Print "Namesheet: " & Namesheet
    Debug.Print "nameRange: " & nameRange
    Debug.Print "nameFile: " & nameFile

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Worksheets(Namesheet).Activate
    Set Plage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Namesheet).Range(nameRange)
    Plage.CopyPicture
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Add(Plage.Left, Plage.Top, Plage.Width, Plage.Height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".png", "png"
    End With

    Debug.Print Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".png", "png"

    Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects(Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
Set Plage = Nothing
End Function

Sub sendMail()
        Application.Calculation = xlManual
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With

        Dim TempFilePath As String
        Dim wsName, rngForImg, fnForImg As String ' e.g. "Sheet1", "B2:I27", "BasicSendEmail"
        wsName = "DM"
        rngForImg = "A1:N32"
        fnForImg = "DM" 'this will be basically the name of the Img

        Debug.Print "wsName: " & wsName ' the ws name
        Debug.Print "rngForImg: " & rngForImg ' the range you want in the Img
        Debug.Print "fnForImg: " & fnForImg ' the name you want for the Img

        'Create a new Microsoft Outlook session
        Set appOutlook = CreateObject("outlook.application")
        'create a new message
        Set Message = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)


        With Message
            .Subject = "PNG My mail auto Object PNG" & Now

            .HTMLBody = "<span LANG=EN>" _
                & "<p class=style2><span LANG=EN><font FACE=Calibri SIZE=3>" _
                & "Hello,<br ><br >The weekly dashboard is available " _
                & "<br>Find below an overview :<BR>"

            'first we create the image as a png file
            Call createPng(wsName, rngForImg, fnForImg)
            'we attached the embedded image with a Position at 0 (makes the attachment hidden)
            TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
            Debug.Print "TempFilePath: " & TempFilePath
            .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & fnForImg & ".png", olByValue, 0

            'Then we add an html <img src=''> link to this image
            'Note than you can customize width and height - not mandatory

            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><B>WEEKLY REPPORT:</B><br>" _
                & "<img src='cid:" & fnForImg & ".png '" & "><br>" _
                & "<br>Best Regards,<br>Ed</font></span>"

            .To = "a@a.com; a@a.com;"
            .Cc = "a@a.com;"

            .Display
            .Send
        End With

        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End Sub
```

Comment: Does it help if you use `Plage.CopyPicture 2`

Comment: i'll try but what is the `2` in that?

Comment: I often use `rangeName.copyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture`    . xlScreen is valued as 1, and 2 is xlPrinter.  [Microsoft help F1 on copypicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821596%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Rory @PatrickLepelletier  tried the `2` but no joy. will follow up Patriks link

Comment: slightly related [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892659/what-excel-vba-actions-are-possible-on-hidden-worksheets-or-workbooks)

Answer (score 1):

i think this may give the same result as your method.
The code i use is :

```
Dim Pic As Shape

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
    .Visible = True
    .Range("F5").MergeArea.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste(Link:=True).Select

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Picture" Then Set Pic = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
end with
```

result : from a range in a different sheet, you get a picture to the activesheet, and a variable (Pic) linked to it.

note : in the example code it is a merged range, adapt to your needs